# Do the Chadwyck-Healey baronets have a coat of arms?

Tags: united-kingdom, nobility, heraldry

The **[Chadwyck-Healey baronets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chadwyck-Healey_baronets)** are one of the more obscure British dynasties. The title is extant - at the time of writing, we're on the fifth baronet - but only the [first baronet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Charles_Chadwyck-Healey,_1st_Baronet) was notable enough to have his own Wikipedia page. The only other famous member of the family seems to be [Cherry Healey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_Healey), a TV presenter and a granddaughter of the fourth baronet.

I was surprised that **I can't seem to find a coat of arms** for the family. Wikipedia - usually so rich in coats of arms - does not have anything, neither does the [fifth baronet's website](https://www.dwyck.com), nor Google. I know that some life peers never seem to have bothered to get a coat of arms, but I assumed that, for any *hereditary* title, a coat of arms was at least de rigueur, if not compulsory in any stricter sense.

**Do the Chadwyck-Healey baronets have a coat of arms?** If so, what does it look like?

Comment: Have you tried an enquiry at the [Royal College of Arms](https://www.college-of-arms.gov.uk/about-us/records-and-collections/2-coa/21-contact-us)?

Comment: You could also ask at the Heraldry Reddit  https://www.reddit.com/r/heraldry/.  You could u suppose that the Chadwyck-Healy baronets quartered the coats of arms of  Chadwyck/Chadwick and of Healey, but there are probably several different coats of arms for different Chadwick and Healey families.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - the coat of arms is recorded in Burke's Peerage & Baronetage, the 1999 edition of which is available to borrow for free [on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/burkespeeragebar0001unse/page/538/mode/1up) and includes the description of the Chadwyck-Healey arms. As MAGolding suggested in a comment, they consist of the Chadwyck coat of arms quartered with the Healey arms.

> **Arms:** 1st and 4th, gules four fusils engrailed and conjoined in bend ermine between two lilies leaved and slipped proper (for HEALEY); 2nd and 3rd, gules an anchor cabled within an orle argent, charged with eight martlets of the field (for CHADWYCK). **Crests:** 1 In front of four fusils engrailed and conjoined fesswise ermine a lily, as in the arms (for HEALEY), 2 A talbot's head couped gules, charged on the neck with an escutcheon argent, thereon a martlet as in the arms (for CHADWYCK). **Motto:** Crede mihi ('Believe in me'). **Creation:** Bt. (UK) 6 May 1919.